# Updating One2One Relationship Object (JPA 2)

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa-2.0, entity-relationship, one-to-one

I have 2 Entities (User.class & Image.class) with a OneToOne Relationship.  There is a problem updating the Image entity.  It works when there is no existing Image Object, I just simply create a new Image, add it to User (using setter) Object and save it, like so:

```
public void addImage(Image image){
    image.setUser(this);
        setImage(image);
    }
```

..

```
 //method used to save the user object
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public User save(User user) {
        User aUser = userRepository.save(user);
        return aUser;
    }
```

Problem occurs when updating the Image.  I have to manually add each image property to the existing image object (see following method).  If I use the above addImage(), it just saves new record without removing the existing Object causing multiple records to appear in the database.

Can somebody have a look and help me identify the problem? Thanks

```
//Add a new Profile Image
public void addImage(Image image){
    Image oldImg = getImage();
    image.setUser(this);
    if(oldImg == null){
        setImage(image);
        return;
    }
        oldImg.setName(image.getName());
        oldImg.setVersion(image.getVersion());
    }


User & Image entity extracts

User Entity

@OneToOne(targetEntity=Image.class, 
        mappedBy="user",
        fetch=FetchType.LAZY, 
        cascade={CascadeType.ALL},
        orphanRemoval=true)
private Image image;
...


Image Entity

@JsonIgnore
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="userid")
private User user;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `equals & hashcode` for both entities.  The persistence provider cannot determine if the objects exists without these methods.

If your using Eclipse you can generate these methods by right clicking the editor, navigating to source and selecting `Generate Equals and Hashcode`.

Comment: Your suggestion results in a StackOverFlowError: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at org.joda.time.chrono.AssembledChronology.getZone(AssembledChronology.java:107)
 at org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology.hashCode(ISOChronology.java:200)
 at org.joda.time.base.AbstractInstant.hashCode(AbstractInstant.java:278)
 at com.core.user.User.hashCode(User.java:249)
 at com.core.user.Image.hashCode(Image.java:94)....